# Bootstrap-Grid 1920 resolution pictures remain small

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, grid

Pictures increase in proportion to 1280 resolution, but pictures do not grow after 1280 resolution, can you help me?

It looks like this at 1920 resolution

[image]

It looks like this at 1280 resolution

[image]

```
    <div  id="logokutu1" class="deneme ortalama neozel logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
      <a href="#">
      <img width="100" height="22" src="marketplace logo/ne-lazimsa-logo.png">
    </a>
    </div> 
      
    <div id="logokutu2" class=" ortalama trendozel logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
      <a href="#">
      <img  width="100" height="34" src="marketplace logo/trendyol-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div> 
    <div id="logokutu3" class="ortalama hepsiozel logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
      <a href="#">
      <img  width="100" height="18" src="marketplace logo/hepsiburada-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
   <div id="logokutu4" class="ortalama  logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="100" height="31" src="marketplace logo/gitti-gidiyor-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div> 
   <div id="logokutu5" class="ortalama n11ozel logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="100" height="35" src="marketplace logo/n11-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div> 
   <div id="logokutu6" class="amazonozel bu ortalama logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="100" height="30" src="marketplace logo/amazon-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div> 
    <div id="logokutu7" class="cicekozel evet ortalama  logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
      <a href="#">
      <img width="100" height="19" src="marketplace logo/ciceksepeti-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's because the images are now expanded to 100% and can't get any larger. You'll need to check out Bootstrap's [media queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Comment: So my site won't run at 1920 resolution?

Comment: @NurullahGüneyli There's one more thing. Why is your img width set to 100? It must be a %, right? Something like 100%, so that the image will be responsive and you can scale up and down. You can't use an img-fluid class of BS here, as it tells the browser not to expand the image larger than its original size.

Comment: What is the solution, I could not fully understand what you mean. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @NurullahGüneyli All I'm saying is, the image won't get any larger unless you tweak the width unit. It has to be relative! Check out this [article](https://css-tricks.com/optimizing-large-scale-displays/#build-with-relative-units) for more information!

Comment: .container{
    display: grid;
    width: 2560px;
    height: 100%;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    justify-items: center;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
}
I made 2560 pixels wide but did not change

Comment: Check this out! I have created a small [example](https://codepen.io/ni_l/pen/gOMaxqE). It looks a bit similar to what you are trying to build. For full-page view, [Click here](https://codepen.io/ni_l/full/gOMaxqE). You can test how the image size increases when the **screen size is >1280px** in chrome dev tools. @NurullahGüneyli